# solve the equation $c_1+c_2 e^{c_3 x}+e^{c_4 x}-e^{c_5 x}=0$

Tags: optimization

How can I solve the equation
$$c_1+c_2 e^{c_3 x}+e^{c_4 x}-e^{c_5 x}=0,$$
where $c_1,\ldots,c_5$ are real numbers?
I encountered this equation when I was solving a maximization problem.
i can say only that all $c_i$s are real x is positive and i want an analytic solution

Comment: Do you know the values of each $c_i$?

Comment: Is the equation true for all $x$ and we are attempting to find the $c_i$?  Or are we assuming we know the c's and are attempting to find x in terms of these constants?

Comment: $x=0, c_2=-c_1$ is an obvious solution.

Comment: Such an equation have no general closed-form solution. However, if all the $c_i$'s are integer multiplies of some number then the equation can be written as a polynomial equation which *may* have an analytical solution.

Comment: Otherwise, Newton method. If you want, provide a set of $c_i$'s.

Comment: @user2612743 i can say only that all $c_i$s are real x is positve